# Is PhoneGap's DB good enough for versioning like CouchDB?

Tags: database, cordova, couchdb, storage

I'm trying to figure out if http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html can handle versioning, conflicts, etc. similar to CouchDB's capabilities.

I'm building a mobile app wherein friends can share data. This data will be manipulated (add, edit, delete) when the app is online or offline. During offline operations, the data changes will be stored locally -- and then sync to a central database when it goes online (and everyone else will sync to that central database).

Obviously, there will be versioning, conflicts, etc. issues. CouchDB supposedly handles this well. However, I want to know if PhoneGap's storage is sufficient for my needs. Will it work or not?

Comment: I don't understand your question -- you'll need to implement all of the features of CouchDB to get what you want ... When you look at the list of features of phonegap storage, how does it compare to your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite has plenty of power for this kinda stuff, though even localstorage is pretty powerful unless you are manipulating data with heavy javascript.  I say try localstorage first as it's very very easy to handle.

Comment: From my understanding, CouchDB has an API. So, my idea was to use the API to "commit" the latest changes from local storage to the central DB. Can you please elaborate on your proposed approach?

Comment: yeah, then you will just store data locally as json objects through localstorage, store.js is a cool plugin for simple operations, otherwise you can implement your own easily.  then just post it to wherever you want to.

Comment: Also worth looking at TouchDB or PouchDB https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/wiki/PouchDB-on-Phonegap